# Adjusting number of rows and columns based on a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I'm new to writing/using scripts for Google sheets.

What I'm needing is to adjust the number of rows and columns based on a cell value.

I'm making a sign-in sheet that needs to add columns based on the number of class days and also add rows based on the number of students. The number of class days would be a number value found in a certain cell on the sheet and then then number of students would also be a number value found in a different cell on the sheet.

I'd appreciate any help!

I'm not really sure where to start with it.

Comment: Have you googled or attempted to solve it yourself beforehand? The creating row portion isn't too difficult, but the creating column portion is more complicated. I will attempt to solve it below while explaining my process

Answer (score 0):

First we need to actually GET the values from those cells to determine how many of each we need:

```
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var a = ss.getSheetByName('YOUR SHEET NAME').getRange('YOUR CELL').getValue()
var b = ss.getSheetByName('YOUR SHEET NAME').getRange('YOUR OTHER CELL').getValue()
```

Now that you have the number of rows and columns you want, you want a for loop to create those rows and columns:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a; i++){
  ss.getSheetByName('YOUR SHEET NAME').appendRow()
}
for(var i = 0; i < b; i++){
  ss.getSheetByName('YOUR SHEET NAME').insertColumnAfter(sheet.getMaxColumns())
}
```

This should accomplish what you're asking for. Please let me know if it doesn't work however.

Comment: I've tried a few different things by looking at different things that I found on Google, but none did what I needed it to.

Comment: I tried what you put there, but it only adds 1 row when I run the script (not when the bell is changed), and only 1 row is added, not the amount of rows that are the value. like I need 10 rows added if cell is 10 and then if cell is 2, then needs to change to being only 2 rows (deleting 8). Same for columns.